# Magento 2 Catalog price rule stops working after a while

Tags: magento, rule, price, catalog

I am facing this weird issue on Magento 2.1.4.
I am running a Catalog Price Rule on certain SKUs and I reindex all the indexers and it's working.

But after a while (I've noticed like a couple or days or something) the rule stops working...(?)

Any ideas what I might be missing? Does it have to do with the indexers?

Much appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you set a date limit in the settings of your price rule?

Comment: @Frank Groot, I haven't set an end date, because the discount is for an indefinate amount of time, so I left it blank, but even if I put let's say May 2030, it will do the same thing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?